# CiviEvent link Parents with Child participants during registration

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm

I am trying to create a registration form for events for children where the parent fills in there contact details (mail/phone) and the name & birthday of the children they want to register for the event.
I have created a Child & Parent Individual in civiCrm with custom fields, I also created a parent of/child of relationship and registering works fine both the parent & the childs are created. But I can not find out how I can automaticaly link the Parent & Childs when the parent registers for the event.

I am using Civicrm 4.6.34 on Drupal.

I also found someone who used a WebForm to solve this, but I don't know how to link this WebForm with an existing CiviEvent : https://civicrm.org/blog/sarahgladstone/recipe-for-handling-youth-registration-with-civicrm

Answer (score 1):

I dont think registering for an event and creating a relationship using the standard CiviCRM event registration pages.

So if you use CiviCRM with Drupal I would go for the webform solution.

There is also a third possibility and that one is using the form processor extension in CiviCRM and then use the CiviMRF to submit you the webform data to CiviCRM. I wrote an example instruction in this blog post: https://civicrm.org/blog/jaapjansma/using-civicrm-form-processor-extension-to-handle-form-submissions-from-an-external

The pro of the form processor solution is that you can create a webform on a remote website. Or in other words, if your website and crm are not on the same site this solution will also works. The con is that it requires a bit more knowledge to set it up.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information. 
Do you know if it is possible to get  the phone number & mail adres that was filled in for the first participant (Parent) and automaticly add this same mail adres & phone number to the additional participants (Children). Then we have the most important information directly available for the children.